# Singular value of identity minus 1-rank matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, singular-values

Given vectors $u,v\in \mathbb{R}^d$, I wonder what we can say about the minimum singular value of $I-uv^\top$? I know that when $u=v$, this matrix is symmetric so it is not hard to compute this. Specifically, I am consider the case where $u=\mathbf{1}$ and $v=\frac{x}{1+\mathbf{1}^\top x}$. Thanks!

== Update:
Actually this matrix has (n-1) linearly-independent eigenvectors $c$'s that are perpendicular to $x$ (with eigenvalue 1) and eigenvector $\mathbf{1}$ with eigenvalue $\frac{1}{1+1^\top x}$. Suppose that $1^\top x > 0$ (which is the case). Then we actually know all the eigenvalues/vectors for this $A=I-uv^\top$ matrix but I do not know how this relates to the singular value of $A$.

== Update 2:
It would be also very helpful if you know something about singular value of $u^\top v\cdot I - uv^\top$ with the above form of $u=\mathbf{1}$ and $v$ with all-positive entries.

Comment: The matrix $uv^T$ will have $u$ as an eigenvector, you should be able to show that easily (in the case $u=\mathbf1$). Unsure how much this helps you.

Comment: Hmm I am not sure. Actually this matrix has (n-1) linearly-independent eigenvectors $c$'s that are perpendicular to $x$ (with eigenvalue 1) and eigenvector $\mathbf{1}$ with eigenvalue $\frac{1}{1+1^\top x}$. Suppose that $1^\top x\neq 0$. Then we actually know all the eigenvalues/vectors for this $A=I-uv^\top$ matrix but I do not know how this relates to the singular value of $A$.

Comment: You can diagonalise the matrix with the basis $u, w_2,..,w_n$ where $w_k$ form a basis for $u^\bot$. Hence the singular values are $1, |1-v^Tu|$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A=I-uv^\top$ and $V=\operatorname{span}\{u,v\}$. Since $AV\subseteq V$ and $A|_{V^\perp}=\operatorname{id}$, at least $n-2$ singular values of $A$ are equal to $1$. Denote the remaining two singular values by $s_1$ and $s_2$. Then
$$
s_1s_2=|\det A|=|1-v^\top u|
$$
and
$$
\begin{aligned}
s_1^2+s_2^2
&=\|A\|_F^2-(n-2)\\
&=\operatorname{tr}\big((I-uv^\top)(I-vu^\top)\big)-(n-2)\\
&=2(1-v^\top u)+\|u\|^2\|v\|^2.
\end{aligned}
$$
Therefore
$$
\begin{aligned}
s&:=\min\{s_1,s_2\}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{s_1^2+s_2^2+2s_1s_2}-\sqrt{s_1^2+s_2^2-2s_1s_2}}{2}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{\|u\|^2\|v\|^2+2(1-v^\top u)+2|1-v^\top u|}\,-\,\sqrt{\|u\|^2\|v\|^2+2(1-v^\top u)-2|1-v^\top u|}}{2}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{\|u\|^2\|v\|^2+4\max\{1-v^\top u,\,0\}}\,-\,\sqrt{\|u\|^2\|v\|^2+4\min\{1-v^\top u,\,0\}}}{2}.\\
\end{aligned}
$$
It may not seem obvious, but the second largest singular value of $A$ is actually always $\le1$. Hence the minimum singular value of $A$ is $s$.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the late reply. I actually obtained the exact same form as your solution yesterday :) The notice on $V^\perp$ is very nice.